# Javascript - Setting global variables

Tags: javascript, variables, global

I'm running into an issue with setting the value of global variables. When my function GetUserList() is called, it returns an array of globalUsers when it is run inside the function.

However, when I log the console again after running the function, the array being returned is empty. I feel there must be something wrong with the logic, or the manner in which the code is being executed.

I'm seeking that the value of globalUsers is set within the function for future use throughout the rest of the script.

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. See the code below:

```
var globalUsers = [];

function GetUserList(){
    var userList = $().SPServices.SPGetListItemsJson({
                listName: "Users",
                CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' /></OrderBy></Query>",
                async: false,

                mappingOverrides: {
                    ows_Title: {
                        mappedName: "Name",
                        objectType: "Text"
                    },
                    ows_ID: {
                        mappedName: "id",
                        objectType: "Text"
                    },
                    ows_Group: {
                        mappedName: "Group",
                        objectType: "Text"
                    }
                }
            });

            $.when(userList).done(function() {
                thisUserList = this.data;
                globalUsers = thisUserList;
                console.log(globalUsers);
            });
}


    $(document).ready(function () {
        GetUserList();
        console.log(globalUsers);
    }
    );
```

Comment: is there anything inside thisUserList ? what type of data does it hold? did you check the type ? give the data returned by thisUserList if possible

Comment: Did you declare `thisUserList` anywhere? Also try to `console.log(this.data)` whether it returns something and what type

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're not waiting until the `globalUsers` variable has been updated.

In the GetUserList function, you're explicitly waiting for the assignment assignment to complete before logging out the result, whereas the `console.log` in your `$(document).ready` block is executing the log immediately (as GetUserList is non-blocking).

Try logging out the value in dev tools, I bet you'll see what you're expecting (assuming the async assignment has taken place).

Alternatively, you could use a promise to ensure that you're only attempting assignment once the `getUserList` method has completed:

```
function GetUserList () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var userList = $().SPServices.SPGetListItemsJson({
      listName: "Users",
      CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' /></OrderBy></Query>",
      async: false,

      mappingOverrides: {
          ows_Title: {
              mappedName: "Name",
              objectType: "Text"
          },
          ows_ID: {
              mappedName: "id",
              objectType: "Text"
          },
          ows_Group: {
              mappedName: "Group",
              objectType: "Text"
          }
      }
    });

    // Should also handle errors in here somewhere, and reject if they occur...

    $.when(userList).done(function() {
      resolve(this.data);
      console.log('Logging from within getUserList: ', globalUsers);
    });
  })
}


$(document).ready(function () {
  GetUserList().then((userList) => {
    console.log(userList);
    globalUsers = userList; // Global assignment
  })
});
```

Also, cursory *don't use global variables, mmmKay?*

Comment: Thanks for that. How would I then explicitly wait for the execution of GetUserList() inside the $(document).ready block?

Comment: @user3932488 You could pass a callback function like `GetUserList(function(err,data){})` when you invoke it in `$(document).ready`. Inside your `done` handler in `GetUserList(cb)`, you can call the callback function passing it the data when it is available. or use Promises instead of the callback

Comment: Thanks Chirag. I understand what you refer to using the callback function but I'm unsure at what stage I set the value of the global variable?

Comment: You could also return a resolved promise from the `getUserList` method.  I'll update my answer with an example in a bit.